# How to "filter" some values in Excel but to always have consistent number of rows as an output

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

What I would like to find out is how can I achieve that by filtering some values (in my case from **Column F**) for some instances to show me whole range of rows and not only matched rows? In my case that is consecutive 6 rows always (from Row 2 to 7, and then Row 8 to 13 etc..) it doesnt matter if they are emtpy or full, I just need them to be shown on filter and rest "hidden". Also, it might be possible to be more than one match, like in Excel Tables Filter, but for certain number of rows.
****A**s you can see it is combination of empty rows and visible rows.******
Open for all solutions, VBA also.

[image: Examples]

**This is what is expected when I filter out other values..?!**
[image: Ex2]

Comment: You'd need to loop over each cell in the filter column (within each "block") and figure out if you need to hide the whole block, or just hide the non-matching values in that block (which you could likely do using a custom cell format like `;;""`, so they could be restored).  There's no "built-in" method for something like this.

Comment: This is not really "filtering" in the Excel sense. Rather it seems you are "hiding" certain values.  You can do this with either conditional formatting (to make the hidden values invisible), or use VBA to actually remove them.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hmm ok...I can give a try. I knew it was a complicated thing....those chefs and their "amazing" needs :/

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Ok..I will give a try..